# expansion in powers of 'x'

Tags: asymptotics, power-series

under what conditions can a function $ f(x) $ be expanded into inverse powers of 'x' ? for example in the form

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{x^{n}} $$

i believe that one condition is related to the fact that the integral equation (linear)

$$ f(x)= x\int_{0}^{\infty}dyK(yx)g(y) $$

has a solution that can be expanded into a Taylor series of the form

$$ g(y)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(n)y^{n} $$

for some b(n) related to a(n)

Comment: You need that t a normal power series for the function $x\mapsto \begin{cases}f(1/x)&\text{if }x\ne 0\\a(0)&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ exists. Of course, you need in particular that $a(0)=\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}f(x)$ exists